# ¿Como buscar solo por fecha (Día, Mes y Año) en mongoDB por medio del Resolver?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

tengo un sistema en el que quiero comprobar si el titulo del articulo y la fecha en la que se guarda son iguales para mandar un error de que la nota ya se encuentra repetida, pero tengo el siguiente problema, en mongoose guardo la fecha con `Date.now()` y en mongoDB me aparece con el siguiente formato `"2020-05-31T22:37:43.783Z"` y hasta ahorita no he podido encontrar una manera en la que me lance el resultado esperado. Les comparto el código que tengo.

```
nuevaNota: async (_, {input}, ctx) => {

        const {titulo} = input;
        // console.log(titulo);
        const existeNota = await Nota.find({titulo});
        var date = new Date();
        var dia = date.getDate();
        var mes = date.getMonth();
        var anio = date.getUTCFullYear();
        var mesDos = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var fechaHoy = anio + '-' + mesDos + '-' + dia;
        var fecha = fechaHoy.toString();
        console.log(existeNota);

        const fechaNota = await Nota.find({
            "fecha" : { "$eq": new Date(fechaHoy)}
        })
        console.log(fechaNota);


        try {

            //Guardarlo en la Base de Datos
            const nota = new Nota(input);
            nota.save();
            return nota;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir cómo defines el campo`fecha` en tu esquema de Mongoose? El método `now()` devuelve un valor numérico correpondiente a los milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero de 1970 UTC. Por lo tanto tu comparación usando `$eq` fallará (o devolverá `false`) a menos que el valor que uses como comparación sea exactamente el mismo valor almacenado en tu DB. En tu constructor del Objeto Date, solo pasas los valores correspondientes a dia, mes y año, faltando los de horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos. Así nunca obtendrás el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Si, el campo fecha lo estoy definiendo con los siguientes valores: `type: Date,
        default: Date.now()`

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea consultar una Base de Datos de [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) de tal forma que se pueda filtrar por el campo `titulo` de tipo `String` y el campo `fecha` de tipo `Date`.

Las fechas se almacenan en la Base de Datos en el formato *datetime*, es decir, se almacena tanto la fecha como la hora (con sus correspondientes minutos, segundos, milisegundos). Además, la fecha se almacena en zona horaria `UTC`.

Se desea encontrar los documentos de la colección que hayan sido creados en una fecha particular, sin tomar en cuenta la hora, y que tengan como título un valor específico.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma de hacerlo en una consulta ([`query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), sería usando el operador [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) para poder calcular el año, mes y día de la fecha almacenada en los documentos y compararlos con el año, mes y día de la consulta (fecha de la consulta).

El operador `$expr` de Mongo, nos permite escribir expresiones de tipo [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) para ser usadas en una [consulta](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) simple.

La expresión que buscamos es de comparación. Vamos a comparar año, mes y día del mes. Además se deben cumplir todas estas comparaciones, por lo tanto necesitamos tanto una forma de comparar, como una forma de indicar que todas las comparaciones se deben cumplir.

- Operador [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html): Usaremos este operador de agregación para indicar que vamos a comparar igualdad entre 2 valores, los cuales debemos pasar como elementos de un `array`.
- Operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/): Es un operador de agregación para indicar que se deben cumplir 2 o más condiciones simultáneamente. En este caso se deben cumplir las coincidencias de año, mes y dia.
- Operadores [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/), [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) y [`$dayOfMonth`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/): Estos operadores los usaremos para obtener precisamente el año, el mes y el día de la fecha almacenada en el campo `fecha` como de la fecha de la consulta.

La consulta la podemos escribir así:

```js
//...
{ titulo } = input;
let today = new Date();
let query = {
  titulo,
  $expr: { // la siguiente es una expresión de agregación
    $and: [ // indica que cada comparación entre elementos del array se debe satisfacer
      { $eq: [ { $year:   '$fecha' }, { $year: today } ] },  // devuelve true si se cumple la igualdad de loss elementos
      { $eq: [ { $month:   '$fecha' }, { $month: today } ] },
      { $eq: [ { $dayOfMonth: '$fecha' }, { $dayOfMonth: today } ] } 
    ]
  }
}
try {
  let notas = Nota.find(query);
  if(!notas.length) {
    // proceso en caso de que no existan notas
  } else {
    // proceso en caso de que sí exitan notas
  }
} catch(e) {
  // manejo de excepciones de promesas
}
```

Como se aprecia he usado la siguiente sintáxis:

```
{$year: '$fecha'}, ...
```

Esto indica que el parámetro que recibe el operador `$year` es el valor del campo `fecha`, el cual indico usando el símbolo `$` delante del nombre.

Esta consulta devuelve una lista con todos los documentos que cumplan la condición. Para determinar si la lista contiene elementos utilizo la propiedad `length` del tipo `Array`. Un valor 0 indica que no se encontraron documentos y cualquier otro valor indica que si se encontraron elementos.

Tu código podría verse aproximadamente así:

```js
nuevaNota: async (_, {input}, ctx) => {
  let {titulo} = input;
  // console.log(titulo);
  let today = new Date();
  let query = {
    titulo,
    $expr: { // la siguiente es una expresión de agregación
      $and: [ // indica que cada comparación entre elementos del array se debe satisfacer
        { $eq: [ { $year:   '$fecha' }, { $year: today } ] },  // devuelve true si se cumple la igualdad de loss elementos
        { $eq: [ { $month:   '$fecha' }, { $month: today } ] },
        { $eq: [ { $dayOfMonth: '$fecha' }, { $dayOfMonth: today } ] } 
      ]
    }
  }
  try {
    let  notas = await Nota.find(query);
    if(!notas.length) {  // si NO hemos encontrado documentos
      //Guardarlo en la Base de Datos
      let nota = new Nota(input);
      nota = await nota.save();
      return nota;
    }
    // código en caso de que exista ya una nota en la BD
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // manejo del error
  }
}
```

Puedes ver una implementación aproximada de esta consulta en [este](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-fUMh5l69Fn) enlace.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota:** El uso del operador $expr está limitado a MongoDB versión 3.6 y superior.

Comment: +1 por que la estructura que le das a tus respuesta me agrada bastante por que son muy didácticas

Comment: muy buena esta respuesta gracias me sirvio