# Filtros de fechas en MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, date, nosql, mongod

Tengo dudas para hacer consultas con el campo fecha lo que quiero es consultar por día es decir que en el cliente le mande el día por el cual  se va a filtrar y que MongoDB me devuelva todos lo registros que tengan ese día, sin necesidad de especificar la hora, lo mismo para el mes y el año.

Ya intenté con:

```js
{"fecha":{"$eq": new Date("2020-08-07") }}
```

y no me devuelve nada hasta que le ponga el resto de la fecha.

Les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se necesita realizar una consulta a una Base de Datos en MongoDB usando como filtro un valor que representa una fecha, sobre un campo de tipo `Date`. Se desea que la consulta devuelva todos los documentos que coincidan en día, mes y año, sin importar la hora.

Actualmente la consulta se realiza usando el siguiente filtro:

```
{"fecha":{"$eq": new Date("2020-08-07") }}
```

Sin embargo esto tiene el problema de que no devuelve ningún documento si la fecha no es exacta.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución al problema es sencilla y se tienen algunas opciones para realizar la consulta.

**Filtrando por rango**

Puedes filtrar por fecha para un rango particular de horas, usando el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) junto con los operadores [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html) y [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/index.html), aprovechando que el tipo `Date` representa un valor numérico, por ejemplo:

```js
{ 
  $and: [
    {fecha: {$gte: new Date("2020-08-07T00:00:00.000Z")}},
    {fecha: {$lte: new Date("2020-08-07T23:59:59.999Z")}}
  ]
}
```

Como se observa hemos creado un rango con la fecha de la consulta que deseamos, en este caso para el día 07 del mes 08 del año 2020, empezando a las 00 horas exactas y terminado a las 23 horas 59 minutos, 59 segundos y 999 milésimas de segundos del mismo día.

La cadena usada para construir la fecha está en formato [ISO-8601](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) y en zona horaria UTC. Si deseas filtrar usando una zona horaria específica, debes sustituir la letra "z" de la cadena por el valor (+/-)HH:MM correspondiente. Por ejemplo, si deseo una consulta usando zona horaria GMT-4, debo hacer lo siguiente:

```
new Date("2020-08-07T00:00:00.000-04:00") // zona horaria GMT-4
```

Puedes ver una implementación en el siguiente [enlace](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LLDdICQZOxw) (has de hacer clic en el botón `run`).

Puedes probar cambiando el rango de hora, por ejemplo, en este otro [enlace](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OCDmfB-TDae), utilizo GMT+2 para el rango de horas, pero con la misma fecha, y siendo la misma colección, el resultado es diferente (trae más registros).

**Usando el operador `$expr`**

En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361107/como-buscar-solo-por-fecha-d%c3%ada-mes-y-a%c3%b1o-en-mongodb-por-medio-del-resolver/381653#381653) respuesta, explico exactamente como hacer una búsqueda usando el operador [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) en una [`query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) simple usando [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find). Claro en dicha respuesta se enfoca el código entorno a [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), el cual es un popular ODM para MongoDB.

Sin embargo el código es exactamente el mismo para la `query` escrita en MongoDB (o en algún programa de administración, como [Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/)).

Lo que hacemos es crear una expresión de agregación que podemos utilizar en una consulta de tipo `find()`.

Se utilizan los operadores [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html), [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/), [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/), [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/), [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) y [`$dayOfMonth`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/).

Lo que haremos es construir una expresión de agregación para buscar documentos cuyo campo fecha tenga como año, mes y dia, los valores que coincidan con el parámetro de búsqueda.

La consulta se escribiría de la siguiente forma:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      { $eq: [{ $year: "$fecha" }, { $year: new Date("2020-08-12") }]},
      { $eq: [{ $month: "$fecha" }, { $month: new Date("2020-08-12") }]},
      { $eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: "$fecha" }, { $dayOfMonth: new Date("2020-08-12") }]}
    ]
  }
});
```

En [este](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRZMppthfNs) enlace puedes ver el código anterior en funcionamiento para la misma colección que hemos estado trabajando de ejemplo.

Si deseas aplicar zona horaria a la búsqueda, debes usar el siguiente formato:

```
{ $year: { date: "$fecha", timezone: "+02:00" } },
{ $year: { date: new Date("2020-08-12"), timezone: "+02:00" } }
```

Está demás decir que lo debes establecer para ambos campos que vas a comparar.

Nuevamente en [este](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OgWHhYoB8Ax) enlace puedes ver el resultado de la misma consulta usando la zona horaria GMT+2.

**Nota**: El uso del operador `$expr` está limitado a MongoDB versión 3.6 y superior.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de hacerlo es asi yo lo ando usando y me sirve a la perfeccion

```
{"fecha":ISODate("2020-08-07")}
```

la busqueda la realiza solo por la fecha no toma en cuenta la hora del registro den las colecciones, es un poco tarde de responder pero quizas a alguien le sirva en un futuro